# jest enzyme routing how to test component with Route?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I have an `App` component which contains main route definitions:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(theme)}>
        <Route
          path={`${URL_PREFIX}/:module?/:id?`}
          render={() => (<div>
            <MapContainer />
            <NavigationBox />
            <FeedbackMessage />
          </div>)}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path={URL_PREFIX}
            render={() => (
              <Redirect to={`${URL_PREFIX}/restaurants`} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the main file, where I have render function, which renders `App` on proper HTML node and wraps it everything what is needed:

```
const render = (messages) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};
```

So far everything works.

I also tried to write the tests for `App` but this part doesn't work at work at all. It is my test file:

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  describe('should render other components on proper route', () => {
    let renderedComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
      renderedComponent = shallow(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[URL_PREFIX]} initialIndex={0}><App /></MemoryRouter>
      ).dive().dive();
    });

    it('should render <MapContainer />', () => {
      expect(renderedComponent.find(MapContainer).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('should render <NavigationBox />', () => {
      expect(renderedComponent.find(NavigationBox).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('should render <FeedbackMessage />', () => {
      expect(renderedComponent.find(FeedbackMessage).length).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

If I add more `.dive()` I got an error:

```
TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components
```

If there is only 2 dives or 1 dive it says that expected value (1) is different than received (0), so tests fail.

If I try with `render` or `mount` it complains, that store is expected but has value undefined.

Is there any way to test if on the chosen path my components are rendered?